# How to center text into radio button

Tags: android, radio-button

I have customized the original radiobutton with a specific background and by removing the button :

**styles.xml :**

```
<style name="echelle_relecture">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/btn_relecture_echelle</item>
    <item name="android:button">@null</item>
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">center_horizontal</item>
</style>
```

**radio.xml :**

```
<RadioGroup android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/radioGroup1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
        <RadioButton style="@style/echelle_relecture" android:text="@string/day" android:id="@+id/jour" android:checked="true"></RadioButton>
        <RadioButton style="@style/echelle_relecture" android:text="@string/hour" android:id="@+id/hour" android:button="@null"></RadioButton>
        <RadioButton style="@style/echelle_relecture" android:text="@string/min" android:id="@+id/mins" android:button="@null" android:enabled="false"></RadioButton>
</RadioGroup>
```

Despite the "center_horizontal" parameter i can't get the text centered inside the button. How can i do that ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should use `gravity`, not `layout_gravity` to centralize text inside `RadioButton`.

Answer (score 9):

use this

```
android:gravity="center"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<RadioButton
    ...
    android:textAlignment="center"
    ... />
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: This code is as self explanatory as it gets, come on!

Answer (score 0):

Either setting `android:paddingLeft="0dp"` or `android:paddingRight="0dp"` should work to center the text

Answer (score 0):

add the code in your style 

`<item name="android:gravity">center</item>`